# How to remove miliseconds when displaying date/time on website from getdate() column?

Tags: php

I've got a stored procedure which is updating a column as `GETDATE()` .. it's fine but however I want to grab the value from that column which is like that for example: `2014-10-11 22:57:48.550`
and display it on my website without the milieseconds?

**So, how to remove miliseconds when I am displaying it on the website? It's fine to be stored into the database with miliseconds hoever on displaying I want to don't show them...**

That's the function below which is used to grab and display information for last 20 logins however `LTIME` column should be shown without the miliseconds. I've tried a few ways to convert but its not working as it should. Any suggestions how it should be done? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yeah, I tried but couldn't do it. Like convert and etc. I included my function, please help me out. It will be greatly appreciated if you can suggest me what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select convert(varchar(50),GETDATE(),100)
```

This is for SQL Server.If you are using MYSQL instead of SQL Server you need to find the equivalent command.
Hope it helps you.

**EDIT**

Try this if you are using mySQL

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T')
```

Comment: I am trying to convert it however it's not working as it should. I've updated my main post with my function. Would you be able to point me out whats the best to be done ? I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Did you resolve your problem already? If not try the update on my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot however I am using MSSQL Server 2005 and none of these worked correctly. I used `substr()` to remove the last `.miliseconds` Not sure if its good but it works actually .. Thanks a lot!